# MariaDB Galera Cluster

Tags: innodb, clustering, mariadb, xtradb

I have two mariadb servers in cluster that is working galera and xtradb.

it is my primary server configuration:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
query_cache_size=0
binlog_format=ROW
default_storage_engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://
wsrep_cluster_name='cluster1'
wsrep_node_address='172.16.41.34'
wsrep_node_name='node1'
wsrep_sst_method=xtrabackup
wsrep_sst_auth="test:test1234"
log-error=/var/log/mysql.log
```

Slave configuration :

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
query_cache_size=0
binlog_format=ROW
default_storage_engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://172.16.41.34
wsrep_cluster_name='cluster1'
wsrep_node_address='172.16.41.36'
wsrep_node_name='node2'
wsrep_sst_method=xtrabackup
wsrep_sst_auth="sstuser:s3cretPass"
log-error=/var/log/mysql.log
```

After deliberately changed the user in wsrep_sst_auth, I noticed that the servers no problem to connect and synchronize with different user and password .

Do you think that is this a bug in galera?
Is it possible to compromise the cluster?
And also want to ask the traffic between two web server in the cluster that is encrypted?
Thanks :)

Comment: Did you change `wsrep_sst_auth` on both machines, or just one?  I don't think server X's setting being wrong will stop X from connecting to and synching from Y... I think X's setting being wrong will stop Y (or any other node) from synching from X... the donor node's setting is relevant with innobackupex, not the joining node.